# Delete files and folders not containing file ownd by a user

Tags: linux, unix, ubuntu, terminal, backup

Hi I want help with a rm command that can remove all files and folders not containing any files created by a specific user

so say i copy a "public" folder where lots of users store there files and this "user1" wants a copy of all his files and folders (not the empty folders)

Answer (score 0):

Try to copy only the files of user1.

```
find publicdir -user user1` -exec cp {} somedir \;
```

When you have used `cp -p` you can still remove the files using

```
find user1dir ! -user user1 -exec rm {} \;
```

Comment: find publicdir -user user1` -exec cp {} somedir \; only copies the files but i need the directorys intact to. like:
parentdir
----------->shared document dir
-------------------->somefiles 
--------------------->importantdoc dir
----------------------> some more files

And if the user doesnt own any files in a directory that dir shouldnt be copied.

I was thinking that i can copy the whole publicdir and then remove all files that doesnt belong to user1. And then check and remove empty dir.

Is that possible or is it a more basic way to do it?

Comment: When you want to keep the dir-structure and not afraid for the overhead copying all files, you can do a `cp -rp` followed by removing files that `! -user user1`. Cleaning up empty dirs can be done with http://unix.stackexchange.com/q/8430/57293.

Comment: so I ran sudo find /publicdir -user user1 -exec cp -rp {} /backup
And it copys all the the files that user1 own and the directories he have created in the public dir. 
But it doesnt copy the parent directories for the files that is in other users directories, is this possible?

Comment: Why not try it?